# Switch emails servers every thousand?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to switch `phpmailer` information to shift email server loads every 1000 emails sent.  For example every 1000 emails sent, I want to use a different server.

- 1-1000 emails use server 1
- 1001-2000 use server 2
- 2001-3000 use sever 1 and so on

So far I am using this:

```
$x =1;
foreach($data as $value) {

if ($x <= 1000) {
  //use server 1
  $x++;
} else {
  //use server 2
  if ($x == 2000) {
    $x = 1;
  }
}
```

Is there a better or more standardized way to achieve this?

Comment: Whats about just set another smtp?

Comment: I instanciate an new phpmailer with the else

Comment: So you mainly ask for a better looping solution?

Comment: It's not nice to send spam! Why not use a mail service, like mailchimp or something instead? Otherwise, if the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. SO is for issues, not reviews.

Comment: @mr.void correct.

Comment: @Magnus.Ericksson  Not cost effective.  Opt-in list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit more elegant than if/else:

```
$phpMailerInstances = ['server1' => $yourInstance, 'server2' => $yourInstance2]

function getServer($currentServer){
    if($currentServer == 'server1')
    {
        return 'server2';
    }
    return 'server1';
}

$currentServer = 'server1';
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    echo $i.PHP_EOL;
    if($i % 1000 == 0)
    {
        $currentServer = getServer($currentServer);
        echo '>>>>>'.$currentServer.PHP_EOL;
    }

    $phpMailerInstances[$currentServer]->send()
}

?>
```